# ng-pick-datetime version 7 in Angular 6 project, try to not show Time, just show date and close once date is selected

Tags: angular6, datetimepicker

Using **ng-pick-datetime version 7 in Angular 6 project**, try to not show Time, just show date and close once date is selected

In Angular 6 project I have used,

package.json:

```
"ng-pick-datetime": "^7.0.0",
"ng-pick-datetime-moment": "^1.0.8",
```

Component.module :

```
import { OwlDateTimeModule, OwlNativeDateTimeModule, OWL_DATE_TIME_FORMATS } from 'ng-pick-datetime';
import { OwlMomentDateTimeModule } from 'ng-pick-datetime-moment';

export const MY_MOMENT_FORMATS = {
  parseInput: 'llll LT',
  fullPickerInput: 'llll',
  datePickerInput: 'llll',
  timePickerInput: 'LT',
  monthYearLabel: 'MMM YYYY',
  dateA11yLabel: 'LLLL',
  monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
};

providers: [
    { provide: OWL_DATE_TIME_FORMATS, useValue: MY_MOMENT_FORMATS },
  ]
```

Component.html:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="form-control-label">Check Due Date</label>
<div class="input-group">
<div class="input-group-prepend">
<div class="input-group-text">
<i class="icon ion-calendar tx-16 lh-0 op-6"></i>
</div>
</div>

      <input class="form-control owlDateTime" [owlDateTime]="dt3" 
      [owlDateTimeTrigger]="dt3" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM" 
      name="dueDate" [(ngModel)]="selectedCheck.dueDate" id="dueDate">

      <owl-date-time #dt3></owl-date-time>

</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found these solutions, so I think **ng-pick-datetime** version 7 is most strong datetimepicker for **Angular 5/6/7** projects.

**1-If the Date field is sotred in DB as DateTime and we want to show Date and Time in UI**

Package.json

```
"moment": "^2.23.0",
"ng-pick-datetime": "^7.0.0",
"ng-pick-datetime-moment": "^1.0.8"
```

component.module.ts

```
import { OwlDateTimeModule, OwlNativeDateTimeModule, OWL_DATE_TIME_FORMATS } from 'ng-pick-datetime';
import { OwlMomentDateTimeModule } from 'ng-pick-datetime-moment';

export const MY_MOMENT_FORMATS = {
  parseInput: 'llll LT',
   fullPickerInput: 'llll',
   datePickerInput: 'llll',
  timePickerInput: 'LT',
  monthYearLabel: 'MMM YYYY',
  dateA11yLabel: 'LLLL',
  monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
};
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    OwlDateTimeModule,
    OwlNativeDateTimeModule,
    OwlMomentDateTimeModule,
    FormsModule,
    SharedModule,
    MedSetupPackageModule,
    NursingUnitModule,
    BedModule,
    ResidentModule,
    AllergyModule,
    DiagnoseModule,
    ResidentxdiagnoseModule,
    ResidentxallergyModule],

  providers: [
    { provide: OWL_DATE_TIME_FORMATS, useValue: MY_MOMENT_FORMATS },
  ]
})
```

IMPORTANT! 
JUST when you set this configuration and define it as provider for OWL_DATE_TIME_FORMATS, it affects all other modules on the project that use the OwlDateTimeModule

component.ts

```
Get the data that includes the dateTime field via an angular service
```

component.html

```
<div class="col-lg-4">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="form-control-label">Go Live Date <span class="tx-danger">*</span></label>
                <div class="input-group">
                  <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <div class="input-group-text">
                      <i class="icon ion-calendar tx-16 lh-0 op-6"></i>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <input class="form-control owlDateTime" [owlDateTime]="dt2" [owlDateTimeTrigger]="dt2" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM" name="goLiveDate" [(ngModel)]="selectedProject.goLiveDate" id="goLiveDate">
                  <owl-date-time #dt2></owl-date-time>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

**2-If the Date field is sotred in DB as DateTime and we just want to show Date and no Time in UI**

Modify component.module to

```
export const MY_MOMENT_FORMATS = {
  parseInput: 'LL',
  fullPickerInput: 'LL',
  datePickerInput: 'LL',
  monthYearLabel: 'MMM YYYY',
  dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
  monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
};
```

Modify, component.html to

```
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="form-control-label">Invoice Due Date</label>
        <div class="input-group">
          <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <div class="input-group-text">
              <i class="icon ion-calendar tx-16 lh-0 op-6"></i>
            </div>
          </div>
          <input class="form-control owlDateTime" [owlDateTime]="dt3" [owlDateTimeTrigger]="dt3" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM" name="invoiceDueDate" [(ngModel)]="selectedProject.invoiceDueDate" id="invoiceDueDate">
          <owl-date-time [pickerType]="'calendar'"  #dt3></owl-date-time>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**3- If the Date field is sotred in DB as nvarchar**

So, first we change the format of date property in Front-End by using moment.js then choose one of the described options.

Modify, component.ts

```
import * as moment from 'moment';

birthDate:string;

this.birthDate = moment(Object.birthDate).format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss");
```

**Then choose one of the above options to show time or not show time by modify module and html**

Hopefully this answer help to people that need to work by a datetimepicker on Angular projects.